# Python regex with unicode strings not working

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to receive the prices from the following string:

**"€29,95 ipv €69,95 – ezCast M2 Original "**

With the following regex:

```
[\$\£\€](\d+(?:.\d{1,2})?)
```

According to regex testers the above regex works fine (I receive 29,95 and 69,95 without currency, so that's good)... But in python it doesn't. I think it's because of the fact python unicodes strings. Because if I print the string on my screen I get:

```
[u'\u20ac29,95 ipv \u20ac69,95 \u2013 ezCast M2 Original']
```

I tried the following codes:

```
p = re.findall('[\$\£\€](\d+(?:.\d{1,2})?)',str(prices))
p = re.findall(u'[\$\£\€](\d+(?:.\d{1,2})?)',str(prices))
p = re.findall(ur'[\$\£\€](\d+(?:.\d{1,2})?)',str(prices))
p = re.findall(r'[\$\£\€](\d+(?:.\d{1,2})?)',str(prices))
```

None of those work...
But the one below DOES work:

```
p = re.compile('(\d+(?:.\d{1,2})?)')
        #
        for m in p.findall(str(prices)):
            print m
```

But then I receive ALL numbers and I just want the numbers behind a currency.

Anyone who can help me out?

Comment: Try `r'[$£€](\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?)'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the string into unicode by decoding it.

```
>>> prices = "€29,95 ipv €69,95  ezCast M2 Original "
>>> re.findall(ur'[\$\\€](\d+(?:.\d{1,2})?)', prices.decode('utf-8'))
[u'29,95', u'69,95']
```

Comment: Thanks! It brought me on the right path! I only needed to add .pop() to prices to get the first item from the list. .decode('utf-8') wasn't necessary anymore :)

Comment: Useful and concise answer. :) +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex :

```
.*?(\d+,\d+).*?ipv.*?(\d+,\d+).*?
```

It ignores € sign and depends on "ipv" separator.
You must get \1 and \2 elements

Answer (score 0):

You need to `encode` the string:

```
>>> prices = u'\u20ac29,95 ipv \u20ac69,95 \u2013 ezCast M2 Original'
>>> p = re.findall('[\$\£\€](\d+(?:.\d{1,2})?)',prices.encode('utf8'))
>>> p
['29,95', '69,95']
```